# not entering in Jquery function

Tags: c#, jquery

I am pretty new to jquery, my problem is that I have done jquery function in a page which inherits from master page. For some reason the function is totally ignored as if there is nothing and the page is loaded without any script.

Do I need to do something in the page load in the code behind? Underneath I am showing the function;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 0;
    var images = [
        'child.jpg',
        'girl.gif',
        'sponsor.jpg'
    ];

    $('#Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[0]);

    setInterval(change_image, 5000);

    function change_image() {
        index++;
        if (index >= images.length) 
            index = 0;
        $('#Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[index]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is this script located? In the `<head>`?

Comment: The script is done in a content place holder.

Comment: I have done a content place holder in the head of my master page and this page inherits from the master page

Answer (score 3):

First thing to do is to run your jQuery code **after** the *DOM ready* event so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 0;
    var images = [
        'child.jpg',
        'girl.gif',
        'sponsor.jpg'
    ];

$(function(){ // added this line

    $('#Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[0]);

    setInterval(change_image, 5000);

      function change_image() {
               index++;
            if (index >= images.length) index = 0;

            $('#Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[index]);

    }

}); // and this one
</script>
```

Second thing is to make sure jQuery library is included in the page (*before the above code*)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the script is executing before the DOM has finished loading. Try surrounding your code with a document ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* your code as you posted */
    });
</script>
```

See the docs for an explanation of you need this: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your script after the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var index = 0;
        var images = ['child.jpg', 'girl.gif', 'sponsor.jpg'];

        $('#Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[0]);
        setInterval(change_image, 5000);

        function change_image() {
            index++;
            if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
            $('#Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[index]);
        }
    });
</script>
```